# php dropdown list from array not populating

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, drop-down-menu, array-population

I have been having trouble populating a select element with PHP. Currently, I create an array with information pulled from a database. This is used to edit or insert an entry into a logbook for my record keeping.

The variables used in the code deal with customer numbers and customer names, if that helps give any extra relevance.

The method outlined below works perfectly in the case that it is not a new entry (editing an existing entry), but the options do not populate in the case of a new entry (where $ID == 0).

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
connectDB();
$mons = "SELECT * FROM mons ORDER BY mName ASC";
$mons = queryHashArray($mons);
disconnectDB();

<tr><td><select name="mID"> <?php
foreach($mons as $m) { 
  if($ID == 0) { ?>
      <option value="<?= $m['cusNum'] ?>"><?= $m['mName'] ?></option> <?php }
  else { ?>
      <option value="<?= $m['cusNum'] ?>" <?php if($record['mID'] == $m['cusNum']) echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?> ><?= $m['mName'] ?></option> <?php 
      } 
  }?> 
  </select></td>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I could not find an example online that was specific enough to my issue. I hope it is something small and simple that I have overlooked.

UPDATE:

Below is the page source from editing an existing entry and from a new entry.

Existing Entry: Due to privacy concerns, option text has been changed to "Name Omitted".

```
<tr><td><select name="mID">         <option value="3" selected="selected" >Name Omitted</option>        <option value="0"  >Name Omitted</option>           <option value="0"  >Name Omitted</option>
```

New Entry:

```
<tr><td><select name="mID"> <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/folder/public_html/subfolder/file.php</b> on line <b>265</b><br />

</select></td>
```

$record is defined elsewhere in the code and is the record which is being edited. If it is a new record, all values are set to ''.

Does this help?

Comment: Is this the whole piece of code? You never dropped out of php (before the tr/td section), but you drop in and out afterwards. So it feels like you left a chunk of code out.

Comment: after the line `disconnectDB();` put this in: `var_dump($mons)` and tell us what it says

Comment: You don't get any option displayed in the pull down when clicking on it?

Comment: What do you see when you look at the HTML in View Source?

Comment: @MJB - I left out the intro code, but I do indeed switch into and out of php mode.

Comment: I see `$_GET['ID']` then I see `$record['mID']` - Probable mismatch? Plus, do you have any form tags? I don't see any.

Comment: Where is `$record` being populated from? As it stands, it's currently undefined. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- - $record is instantiated elsewhere in the code. The select element is within a form. $record['mID'] is a foreign key, ID is the primary key. mID checks the customer ID (cusNum) for equivalence.

Comment: Clearly `$mons = queryHashArray($mons);` does not work when `$_GET['ID']` is not defined. Something related to login credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `queryHashArray` function isn't returning an array when the ID is 0.
Make sure that the ID or the $_GET['ID'] variable isn't overwriting one used in your function.

Try `print_r($mons)` just after you run the function. That will show you what the function is returning.

Comment: Also, share with us your code for the `queryHashArray` function.

Comment: So, my $mons query was within an else case that would query it only if ID != 0. That was embarrassing, but I would not have caught it without your help.